# Does Flutter scale differently when used as an Element Embedding?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to integrate a Flutter Widget into an existing Next.js-Website by using the new [Flutter Element Embeddings](https://flutter-forward-demos.web.app/#/) feature presented this year during FlutterForward. The integration worked seamlessly, but I had issues regarding the responsiveness and scale of the app. It looks like when opened on a mobile browser (I tried Safari and Chrome), the embedded Flutter Widget would scale by factor 0.5.

So I took a step back and tried to integrate the vanilla Flutter Counter app:

- I created a new flutter app
- I modified the Home Screen to just display the current screen width (`MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width`)
- I modified the default `index.html` inside the `web` folder as follows:

```
<head>
   ...
   <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
   <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="contents"></section>
  <article>
    <div id="flutter_target"></div>
  </article>
  </section>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Embed flutter into div#flutter_target
      let target = document.querySelector("#flutter_target");
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine({ hostElement: target, }).then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

- I added a css file under css/style.css:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/** The style for the DIV where flutter will be rendered */
#flutter_target {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I ran the app

- on Web (localhost)
- I opened the website via the mobile Safari Browser on another Simulator
- and locally on an iOS Simulator as a Flutter App

This is what I got:

[image: Flutter Web vs. Element Embedding vs. Flutter iOS App]

As you can see, the Flutter Web App scales just as expected on Chrome (left) and when running as a Flutter App (right). I would have expected the Safari mobile view (middle) to look just like the view on the right, but as you can see, `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width` outputs a value more than double as big as the right one (980), even though the right Simulator has a larger physical screen!

I then went on doing crazier things and tried out this CSS:

```css
#flutter_target {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    transform: rotate(-14.1deg) scale(0.80) translate(-539px, -45px);
    width: 316px;
    height: 678px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

And this came out:

[image: Wild CSS]

So if i constrain the div in which Flutter is rendered, the correct size is output by `MediaQuery`. But for some reason, the whole website is scaled down by the factor 2 when viewed on a mobile browser...

Any ideas why the Element Embedding scales weirdly and how I can overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

As always: a one-liner does the trick :)

Insert

```html
<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
/>
```

in the `index.html` and you're good to go!

It prevents any scaling from the user client to happen, so we circumvent the problem on mobile browsers. The golden line is `user-scalable=0`, which prevents the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: Please add an explanation of what this line of code does.